# Custom authentication in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am working on application where authentication is done by Web service which further calls our organisation AD service to authenticate.

Now I want to move my application to Azure but problem is my web service is not exposed outside organisation. So I can't use web service on Azure to authticate.

Then I searched for Azure AD and found that Azure AD it self provides authenticate and store users data to their data center.

How can I integrate my organisation AD account to Azure AD ?

Comment: Can you share what you've searched for and what results you've found?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for Azure AD Connect. See
[Integrate your on-premises directories with Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect)

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have to modify my application (c#.net) code to use this service?

Comment: Yes. You have to e. g. modify the owin pipeline (startup.cs) to use AAD authentication.